# What are the effects of additional layers in Power MOSFET in terms of internal resistance and its trigger voltage?

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics

[image]

As you can see in the attached image, due to the additional doping layers between the source and drain the MOSFET achieves a higher control of voltages and therefore can be used in power applications. Unfortunately, one of the counter effects is that each of these layers has a resistance and when all of them are added they increased the internal resistance value. Then comes my question about. If I have a Power MOSFET that has a higher value of internal resistance compared to a common one, does the power device has a higher trigger voltage or the output current might be lower than the input?

Comment: The output current always equals the input current. Electrons are not lost in the process.

Comment: *If I have a Power MOSFET that has a higher value of internal resistance compared to a common one* What is "common one"? Do you mean the classic structure of a planar (horizontal) NMOS? It would be "silly" to make a Power MOSFET with a higher internal resistance. So **by design** the resistance is kept low by **high doping levels**  and making the MOSFET **wide**.

Comment: *does the power device has a higher trigger voltage* Read up on MOSFETs, they don't have a "trigger voltage" but a **threshold voltage** (\$V_t\$) and for good conduction (low \$R_{DS,on}\$) you want to apply a \$V_{GS}\$ that is much larger than \$V_t\$. The threshold voltage is mainly determined by the **doping levels** of the source area under the gate and the **gate oxide thickness**.

Comment: Also comparing a vertical Power MOSFET to a "standard" horizontal (planar) MOSFET will be confusing to a beginner. I would not recommend this as the Power MOSFET is a **very different structure** even though their operation is quite similar. So you're essentially comparing apples to oranges.